# real analysis, Lp space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, and $q$ be the conjugate exponent of $p$. let $S$ be a dense subset of $L^q(E)$. Show that if $g\in L^p(E)$ and 
$\int_E fg\, d\lambda=0$ for all $f\in S$, then $g=0$.

could you help me please?

hint use Riesz representation

Answer (score 1):

1. The functional $\Lambda \colon f \in L^q \mapsto \int_E fg\, d\lambda$ is continuous;
2. $\ker \Lambda$ contains the dense subset $S$, and therefore $\ker \Lambda = L^q$.
3. By the Riesz representation theorem, $g=0$ is the unique possibility to get $\Lambda = 0$.

Comment: Now I am thinking about the inverse argument. If $g$ is not identically $0$ and doesn't belong to $L^q$, let $S$  to be the set in $L^p $ such that any $f $ in $S$, we have $\int fg=0$.  Then can we say that $S $ is dense in $L^p$?